# How to force python to unlock files on macOS

Tags: python, macos, file, locking

I am using Python to automate some installations in my everyday workflow.

The installation requires mounting a .dmg file to the system in order to start and complete the installation. Everything works fine until I try to eject/unmount the attached volume, it gives an error that the volume is used by Python and cannot be ejected/unmounted. The installation process is already completed by the time the unmount is executed, so in theory, files should no longer be in use.

Force unmount helps with the unmount process, but for some reason, it interferes with subsequent subprocess.Popen command that starts the installed application and the app crashes at startup. The crash doesn't occur if the volume is not unmounted, which is a sign the issue is caused by the unmount process.

I would like to try to unmount the volume without forcing the process, but I don't know how to unlock the files being used by Python for the installation. Is there a way to force python to unlock those files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll need to figure out what's still open on the image, and troubleshoot why it isn't closed. I'd have the script pause at the point where you want to unmount the image, and use [the `lsof` command](https://ss64.com/osx/lsof.html) to see what's still open. Note: if the installer is running as root (or anything other than your interactive user), you'll need to run `lsof` as root as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It looks like I have forgotten I was changing the current-working-dir to a folder inside the mounted-volume, to run the installer. When the installation is completed I didn't switch the CWD to another place and of course, this introduces issues with the unmount process and also all other subprocesses were affected negatively, they often crash without any obvious reason. Switching the CWD to HOME before unmounting the volume and start the subprocesses fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the fact the current working directory was set to a folder inside the mounted volume. Switching the CWD to HOME before unmounting process and subprocess execution fixes the issue.